# Confused about JavaScript Regex Multiline mode

Tags: javascript, regex, multiline

Still pretty new to Javascript and I am struggling using multiline regex.

Typically the boundaries of the regex are `^` for the start of the line and `$` for the end of the current line. Thus, my regex is constrained and only runs between `^` and `$`.

Now in multiline mode, how do I set up the boundaries? I've looked at several examples and it is just eluding me.

If my feed looks like this

```
Joe's item list 
Item one is Abc
Item two is xyz 
Item three is 123
End of Item List
```

my typical regex would look like `^Item (\w+) is (\w+)$`.

But I want my regex to only fire between the start and end lines and want to grab that this is Joe's item list. Am I just thinking about this bassackwards thinking I should use multiline regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiline mode in javascript with the `m` modifier. The global `g` modifier means it will return an array containing all matches:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmfmg1c1/3/)

```
/^Item (\w+) is (\w+)$/gm
```

I'm not sure how you are using your regex or what you mean in thinking there might be something wrong with using multiline regex... but this could be imitated without multiline mode with something like this:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmfmg1c1/5/)

```
/(?:^|\n)Item (\w+) is (\w+)(?=\n|$)/g
```

If you're wanting to pull out the capture groups, you could do something like this:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/owym3oyp/)

```
var matches = []
var regex = /^Item (\w+) is (\w+)$/gm;
var match = null;
while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
    matches.push({
        itemNumber: match[1],
        itemName: match[2]
    });
}
```

Comment: Well, you might as well go all the way and just remove your first 3 solutions.